# Can't Bind ContextPresenter.ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datatemplate, contentpresenter

I wanna Bind the `ContentTemplateProperty` of `ContentPresenter` :

```
<UserControl x:Class="MVVM.WPF.View.ControlViews.ParametersControlView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008">
         <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                 Content="{Binding ExtraConsole.ViewModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 ContentTemplate="{Binding Source=ExtraConsole.DataTemplate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ParametersGenericViewModel : ParametersViewModel
{
        public ParametersGenericViewModel()
        {
             DataTemplate = (DataTemplate)new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(DataTemplateAddresses.Parameters, UriKind.Absolute) }[DataTemplateKeys.Parameters];
        }
            ParametersConsole extraConsole;
            public ParametersConsole ExtraConsole
            {
                get { return extraConsole; }
                set
                {
                    extraConsole = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("ExtraConsole");

            }
        }
```

All other bound controls update correct and value of ExtraConsole , ViewModel and DataContext in ExtraConsole  class notify as change  but 
I change the `ExtraConsole.DataTemplate` And `Notify` its `Property Changed`

but no changes happen to `UI` .

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is the `ContentPresenter`? (in the template in the DataTemplate). What is `ExtraConsole`, could you show it? Please, show more code.

Comment: @Anatoliy Nikolaev: added more , thanks